# How can I restrict LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made two tables like this

```
degree_plan                              student_record
------------------------------      ----------------------------
major    course     course_no        ID       course_no     grade        
------------------------------      ----------------------------
COE      COE200        1             4455        1           A
COE      COE305        2             4455        2           C
COE      COE400        3             3333        4           B
SWE      SWE214        4
SWE      SWE344        5
SWE      SWE444        6
```

`course_no` is the relationship between the tables

How I can write query in SQL to give me like this `where ID=4455 and the major = COE`

```
--------------------------
major   course       grade
--------------------------
COE     COE200        A
COE     COE305        C
COE     COE400        NULL
```

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Just make an inner join or left join on course_no. Check some documentation about this join.

Comment: I tried left join but retrieve all the left tablel

Comment: I need retrieve the left table where the major = COE

Comment: @Steven what is the sql you tried? You don't even give it to us. How can people help you?

Comment: select * from degree_plan p, studen`t_record s where p.course_no = s.course_no and course like 'COE%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
select a.mjor, a.course, b.grade 
from degree_plan as a
left join student_record as b on a.course_no=b.course_no and b.id=4455
where a.major='COE'
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight i m developer. I can't explain in detail. I just given solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from degree_plan 
left join studen`t_record 
on studen`t_record.course_no = degree_plan.course_no 
where major = 'COE'
```

you need major in the where to filter

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight At this time it has an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select a.major, a.course, b.grade
from degree_plan a
left join studen`t_record b on b.course_no = a.course_no
where a.major = 'COE'
```

You don't even need like clause, since major field is not longer than COE

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT degree_plan.major, degree_plan.course, studen't_record.grade 
     FROM degree_plan
LEFT JOIN Student_record ON degree_plan.course_no=student_record.course_no where degree.major='COE';
```